# Crossdomain request

Tags: html, jquery, request, cross-domain

I try to load static html pages from another server.I make crossdomain request.

```
$(document).ready(function (){  
  $("div[src]").each(function(){
    var staticFileURL = $(this).attr('src');
    $.ajax({
          url: staticFileURL,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          data: {},
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
          },
          success: function() {
                alert("success");
           },
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback'
        });    
    });
 });
```

But I got in chrome error "SyntaxError:Unexpected token <".

In FF "SyntaxError:Invalid xml attribute value".
What's wrong.Could somebody help me?

Comment: usually the "unexpected token <" is the beginning part of an error html like page, some like '<'html><head><title>Error Page</title></head><body>You did an error</body></html>... but you're expecting JSON

Comment: If you visit `staticFireURL` in a browser, what does it produce? Is it valid JSON?

Comment: My html page very easy without tags "<html>" and "<head>".It's kind of <div>Data</div>

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is to get json data from the server, it looks like you are trying to received HTML data.
Try to put your HTML data inside JSON object on the server and then read that HTML on the success callback:

for example, your json data from the server:

`{ html: "<html><head>...</head></html>" }`

also, your success callback should look like:

`success: function(**data**){
}`